# ProcessingJS and HTML web page issue

Tags: html, processing

Hello so I was trying to include a sketch in my html page using the two lines below, but it didn't work:

```
<script src="processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<canvas data-processing-sources="hello-web.pde"></canvas>
```

Of course I made sure to put all the files in the same directory. I already did some sketches that are working fine in Processing software downloaded from processing.org. So I basically followed the instructions here: http://processingjs.org/ and created a hello-web.pde file that contains the setup and draw functions. I keep hearing about web server but I don't really knowwhat to do? any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processingjs doesn't work in chrome. Chrome has disabled some features which it requires. Try with Firefox!

If that's not the case, it could be something in ur pde file.

Answer (score 0):

ProcessingJS on Chrome works fine for me.

First thing you need to do is:

create a local server using 
 [Mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/")

Set your root path.

run your HTML page like so:

```
localhost:myPort/myHMTLPage.html

(eg. localhost:8000/index.html)
```